# Is Belytschko beam defined for 3D or 2D?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, finite-element-method

from the [paper in this link](http://T.%20Belytschko,%20L.%20Schwer:%20Large%20Displacement,%20Transient%20Analysis%20Of%20Space%20Frames;%20International%20Journal%20For%20Numerical%20Methods%20In%20Engineering;%20Vol.%2011,%2065-84%20(1977)) , which is the Belytscko beam. I could not figure out if it is a 3D beam or a 2D one.

if you don't have access to that paper, please check the [page 73 on this link](http://www.lstc.com/pdf/ls-dyna_theory_manual_2006.pdf).

[image: Beam schematic]

what confused me was the schematics on the original paper and the second link. in the beginning the general movements start from 3D but I don't see all the DOFs in the above image

Comment: If you look at section 4.2 of the LS-Dyna manual (page 76), from the parameters used to represent its deformed state it is clearly a 3D beam including torsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 3D beam (6 degrees of freedom at each node).  The figure is 2D just to make things simpler.